# $f+g$ is measurable no matter how it is defined at points where it has the form $\infty-\infty.$?

Tags: measure-theory

> Let  $f$ and $g$ be measurable extended real-valued functions that are finite almost everywhere. Then $f+g$ is measurable no matter how it is defined at points where it has the form $\infty-\infty.$

My attempt:

Let $f$ and $g$ be measurable extended real-valued functions that are finite a.e. Then the sets $D_1,D_2; \{x:h(x)>b\}$ can be written as unions of sets, possibly with an additional set of measure zero. Thus these sets are measurable and $f + g$ is measurable.

Can you give me an easier way of doing this exercise?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove that if $f$ is measurable, and $g$ is a function that agrees with $f$ almost everywhere, then $g$ is measurable.

Comment: This assumes the measure is complete. This is fine here because the question is from the early part of Royden's book where the measure is assumed to be Lebesgue measure, which is complete.